# PL/SQL: ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am compiling this Function but getting ERROR : missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  WFir_get_act_section_cd(firnum IN NUMBER,langcd IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 
               as
          ACTSEC  VARCHAR2(1500);
                 BEGIN
                  begin
  --- ERROR START                       
 select ltrim(max(sys_connect_by_path(NVL(act_long,' ') || '/' || NVL(section,' '),',')),',') as FIR_ACT_SEC into ACTSEC from(select NVL(act_long,' ') || '/' || NVL(section,' '), row_number() over() rn from rep_fir_sections sec
                         INNER JOIN m_act a on sec.act_cd = a.act_cd
                         INNER JOIN m_section c on sec.section_cd = c.section_code
                         and FIR_REG_NUM = FIRNum
                         and a.lang_cd = langcd)   WHERE ROWNUM <=1 start with rn = 1
                      connect by prior rn = rn -1;
                      EXCEPTION
                      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                         NULL;
                   end;
                   return ACTSEC;
                END;
```

---

When we are compiling above function after migrate this function form MYSQL to Oracle i am getting error "missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification"

I don't know why i am getting this ERROR, Please help me to resolve this ERROR

Comment: `row_number() over ()` is incorrect.  To assign a row_number you have to specify `order by some column`.  The system doesn't know what row to assign to #1 if you don't specify an order for the system to put them into.  Even `order by null` or `order by 1` should work; but you'll probably want a specific field or fields to order by.  Put another way, `order by` isn't optional on a Row_number window function. [Doc Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

Answer (score 2):

`Row_number() over ()` is incorrect.

`order by` is REQUIRED for row_number to work.

`Row_number() over (order by Null /*or you decide what field list*/)` .

To assign a row_number you have to specify `order by some column`. The system doesn't know what row to assign to #1 if you don't specify an order for the system to put them into. Even `order by null` or `order by 1` should work; but you'll probably want a specific field or fields to order by.

Put another way, order by isn't optional on a Row_number window function.

[Doc Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)
"...
ROW_NUMBER is an analytic function. It assigns a unique number to each row to which it is applied (either each row in the partition or each row returned by the query), **in the ordered sequence of rows specified in the order_by_clause**, beginning with 1. ..."

This implies without an order by, no row number can be assigned.